# Install Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have **Ubuntu** installed in my pc as the **main operating system**. I **want to dual boot XUbuntu** in this same pc.
Is there a way to do so?

*I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and want to dual boot [xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) 20.04*

*I have searched the internet for the same but did not find my requirement*

Comment: You can install another Ubuntu *flavor* such as Xubuntu using the "Install alongside" option on the installer.  It will shrink your existing install (you can adjust the slider to whatever proportion you prefer) and it'll install and let you select either from `grub`.  You can of course add `xubuntu-desktop` to your existing install (which is my choice, I have both & `lubuntu-desktop` too; though there are costs to this approach)  As this changes your partitioning, backup first!

Comment: FYI:  It's a QA (quality assurance) testcase, so it's validated for each release. See http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/413/builds/220996/testcases/1301/results for today's *groovy* beta  (currently empty; but I did i yesterday I believe)

Comment: As long as you have enough space on your drive/s, you can add as many OSs as you want.  You want to give each OS more than enough space, because it becomes very difficult to add space after.  Installing is almost the same as doing the first OS, but more mistakes are possible, so backups become more important.

Comment: I have multiple installs on two drives. But last install will be the grub that is in control and then you have to manage grub. Grub updates will normally reset that install to first in boot order. I use / (root) of 25 to 30GB and have large data partition for most data normally in /home so all installs can use it. I do not share /home as any experimental settings I do in another install I do not want in main working install.